# Eclipse Maven JavaFX ${maven.home} not specified

Tags: eclipse, maven, javafx, gluon

I am following the [Gluon instructions for a non-Modular Eclipse/Maven/JavaFX project](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven).

When attempting to run the project, I get the following failure.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.7:run (default-cli) on project hellofx: Execution default-cli of goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.7:run failed: ${maven.home} is not specified as a directory: 'C:\Users\adona\eclipse-workspace\hellofx\EMBEDDED'. -> [Help 1]
```

I then tried to run the command directly from the CLI, and got this error:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: C:\Users\adona\.m2\settings.xml
```

Indeed, when I inspected the `.m2\` file location, the only thing showing is a `\repository` directory.

I'm unclear on what to do to remedy this situation. Do I need to directly install Maven? I thought this was handled by adding the .m2 plugin with Eclipse. I also have STS on this Windows 10 laptop. Is it possible the two applications are interfering with each other?

While waiting for an answer, I think I will uninstal STS (don't really need it, I prefer using another copy that I on a Linux PC) and will try uninstalling and reinstalling the Eclipse Maven plugin. I'll report back here if it makes any difference.

EDIT: Removed and reinstalled the Eclipse m2e plugin. Same error, and while many of the files appear to be updated in the `.m2` directory, there is still no `settings.xml` to be found.

EDIT 2: I switched the version of the javafx-maven-plugin from 0.0.7 to 0.0.6 and now the program runs!?

Is the documentation wrong to ask for us to use 0.0.7?

Comment: Hmm, that might be a side effect of the hotfix for JavaFX 17. Error comes from this [line](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/openjfx/JavaFXRunFixMojo.java#L139), that assumes there is a settings file. You can fix it either by using plugin 0.0.6 with JavaFX 17.0.0.1 or probably by adding an empty settings.xml file.

Comment: I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/139) against the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying 0.0.6 when you left your first comment. I tried 17 earlier and decided to roll back to 15 to get better aligned with the documentation as a way of troubleshooting.

Comment: Plugin 0.0.6 works with all JavaFX versions but JavaFX 17, because of this [change](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8264998). Plugin 0.0.7 was released to work with JavaFX 17 (and with all JavaFX versions). JavaFX 17.0.0.1 was released as a hotfix to solve the Maven issues with 17, so you can go back to plugin 0.0.6 if you use JavaFX 17.0.0.1.